# Is there any way to convert view page into PDF with dynamic jquery data in c#

Tags: c#, html, pdf

I have tried to convert view page into PDF in c# but the problem is it's converting only html, i need to convert whole view page with binded data.

**MY CODE :**

```
String htmlCode = client.DownloadString(path);

var pdf = TheArtOfDev.HtmlRenderer.PdfSharp.PdfGenerator
    .GeneratePdf(htmlCode, PdfSharp.PageSize.A4);
```

Comment: PDFs aren’t dynamic. They can’t retrieve things from a web URL and can’t run JavaScript.

Comment: Not sure this is possible. As you can see form the method name `DownloadString` will download a string, namely the HTML for the page. If that's all you're passing to the PDF generator, then it won't know how to pick up the CSS, images, etc, unless they happen to have absolute URLs (ie start with `http` or `https`), which is unlikely for most of the bits you'd need.